# php_svm.dll extension not working for WAMPServer

Tags: php, dll, svm, libsvm, php-extension

I already downloaded the zip file from http://phpir.com/svm/ that contains the dll files for svm php. I copied the libsvm.dll to C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25 and php_svm.dll to C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext.

I also edited php.ini and included extension=php_svm.dll

After restarting my WAMPP, [the php_svm is checked under php extensions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLduS.png)

I tried the sample code below:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array(-1, 1 => 0.43, 3 => 0.12, 9284 => 0.2),
    array(1, 1 => 0.22, 5 => 0.01, 94 => 0.11),
);

$svm = new SVM();
$model = $svm->train($data);

$data = array(1 => 0.43, 3 => 0.12, 9284 => 0.2);
$result = $model->predict($data);
var_dump($result);
$model->save('model.svm');
?>
```

However, it produced an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SVM' not found in C:\wamp64\www\test\index.php on line 7
```

Can someone help me? I don't know how to install the svm php.

Specs:

```
Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25
```

Comment: If you were to **actually read** the page that you give a link to you would find your answer! ___Note that there are currently no 64bit builds available___

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP had all the information required if they had only read the page that they provide a link to.

Comment: Ah, I see. What can you suggest that I do next?

Comment: The solution would be either to install WAMPServer 32bit, or compile the dll yourself in a 64bit environment